# Баг с языком в телеграмм боте Aiogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram

Всем добрый день. Я сделал телеграмм бота, работающего на двух языках - русском и английском. При начале использования у каждого пользователя спрашивается предпочитаемый язык.Затем он сохраняется в переменную lang. И вот вчера столкнулся с такой ошибкой. Предположим я выбрал русский язык. И при использовании бота, в один момент язык может измениться на противоположный. Сам бот не сложный, самый обычный информационный бот. Все текста сохранены в словарь texts в отдельном файле. Словарь texts содержит внутри два словаря: "ru" и "en". И при отправке сообщения я обращаюсь к словарю по типу texts[lang]["FAQ"]. Прошу помочь, так как уже завтра ботом будут пользоваться очень большое количество людей и от него необходимо избавиться. При необходимости могу выложить код на GitHub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переменная lang задается для каждого пользователя отдельно? Если же нет, то при смене языка другим пользователем он будет изменятся и у Вас.

Для этого можно создать простую базу данных и сохранить для каждого пользователя langю. После этого язык не должен изменится случайно и всегда будет использоваться выбранный язык.